# Unset element in array nested, between a time interval

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to remove an element.

I've a reservation with:

```
$StartTime = "14:00"; $EndTime = "16:30";
```

and Array with

```
Array
(
    [Tennis 1] => Array
        (
            [IntervalTime] => Array
                (
                    [Lun] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10:00
                            [1] => 11:00
                            [2] => 12:00
                            [3] => 13:00
                            [4] => 14:00
                            [5] => 15:00
                            [6] => 16:00
                            [7] => 17:00
                            [8] => 18:00
                            [9] => 19:00
                            [10] => 20:00
                        )

                    [Mar] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12:00
                            [1] => 13:00
                            [2] => 14:00
                            [3] => 15:00
                        )

                    [Mer] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 09:00
                            [1] => 10:00
                            [2] => 11:00
                            [3] => 12:00
                            [4] => 13:00
                        )

                    [Gio] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 09:00
                            [1] => 10:00
                            [2] => 11:00
                            [3] => 12:00
                            [4] => 13:00
                        )

                    [Ven] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 09:00
                            [1] => 10:00
                            [2] => 11:00
                            [3] => 12:00
                            [4] => 13:00
                        )

                    [Sab] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 09:00
                            [1] => 10:00
                            [2] => 11:00
                            [3] => 12:00
                            [4] => 13:00
                            [5] => 14:00
                            [6] => 15:00
                            [7] => 16:00
                            [8] => 17:00
                            [9] => 18:00
                        )

                    [Sun] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 09:00
                            [1] => 10:00
                            [2] => 11:00
                            [3] => 12:00
                            [4] => 13:00
                            [5] => 14:00
                            [6] => 15:00
                            [7] => 16:00
                            [8] => 17:00
                            [9] => 18:00
                        )

                )

        )
```

I need to remove element between **$StartTime** and **$EndTime** 
so for "Lun" array need to be removed:

```
                            [0] => 10:00
                            [1] => 11:00
                            [2] => 12:00
                            [3] => 13:00
                            [4] => 14:00 // need remove
                            [5] => 15:00 // need remove
                            [6] => 16:00 // need remove
                            [7] => 17:00
                            [8] => 18:00
                            [9] => 19:00
                            [10] => 20:00
```

I would to foearch the time from **Start** to **End** date, and then remove with:

```
unset($DisponibilitaRoom[$Nomeroom]["IntervalTime"]["Lun"][$index]);
```

Comment: And what Is your question?

Comment: Simple: how can I remove the element beetween StartTime and EndTime? how to intercept all time beetween a range, and unset they?

Comment: But you said how you would do it. Why Are you asking then? Isnt it working as you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correct - simple `unset` should do it - but you need to loop on the times and remove them as:

```
foreach($arr['Tennis 1']['IntervalTime']['Lun'] as $k => $v) {
    if ($v >= $StartTime && $v < $EndTime)
        unset($arr['Tennis 1']['IntervalTime']['Lun'][$k]);
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/vNbMD)

Or you can use [`array-filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) as

```
$arr['Tennis 1']['IntervalTime']['Lun'] = array_filter($arr['Tennis 1']['IntervalTime']['Lun'], function ($v) use ($StartTime, $EndTime) {
    return !($v >= $StartTime && $v < $EndTime);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` with `array_map` and `array_filter`

```
array_walk_recursive($a['Tennis 1']['IntervalTime'], function(&$v) use ($StartTime, $EndTime){
    if($v >= $StartTime && $v <= $EndTime) $v = false;
});
$f['Tennis 1']['IntervalTime'] = array_map('array_filter', $a['Tennis 1']['IntervalTime']);
print_r($f);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/4tNEM